# Elixir & Phoenix - ArgumentError at GET /users/new

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to implement user authentication with the Phoenix web framework on Elixir but stumped by this error.

If I run `changeset = Blog.User.changeset(%Blog.User{})` inside `iex` I get the following error:

```
** (ArgumentError) unknown field "email" for changeset on 
%Blog.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "users">, email: 
nil, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, is_admin: false, name: nil, password:
nil, password_hash: nil, posts: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association 
:posts is not loaded>, updated_at: nil}
  (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1318: Ecto.Changeset.ensure_field_exists!/2
  (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1305: anonymous fn/5 in Ecto.Changeset.validate_required/3
  (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
  (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1304: Ecto.Changeset.validate_required/3
```

Here is my model `web/models/user.ex`:

```
defmodule Blog.User do
  use Blog.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    field :is_admin, :boolean, default: false

    has_many :posts, Blog.Post

    timestamps()
  end

  @required_fields ~w(email)
  @optional_fields ~w(name is_admin)
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @required_fields ++ @optional_fields)
    |> validate_required(@required_fields)
  end
end
```

Comment: It's just a wild guess but `@required_fields` and `@optional_fields` are lists of strings and perhaps `cast` or `validate_required` require a list of atoms.

Comment: @JustMichael You were absolutely right! Thank you!

Comment: Sure, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to share an explicit possible solution based on JustMichael and PatNowak's answers/comments, using

```
@required_fields ~w(some fields)a
```

instead of

```
@required_fields ~w(some fields)
```

results in a list of atoms which `validate_required` requires, and still seems to work with `cast`.

Answer (score 2):

[Ecto.Changeset.cast/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/3) converts keys to atoms, so for cast you can use strings, but [Ecto.Changeset.validate_required/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_required/3) has to deal with keys as atoms, so your `@required_fields` should be list of atoms.

By the way- there should be sigil `~a` for that.